# Combining itertools and multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-itertools

I have a `256x256x256` Numpy array, in which each element is a matrix. I need to do some calculations on each of these matrices, and I want to use the `multiprocessing` module to speed things up.

The results of these calculations must be stored in a `256x256x256` array like the original one, so that the result of the matrix at element `[i,j,k]` in the original array must be put in the `[i,j,k]` element of the new array.

To do this, I want to make a list which could be written in a pseudo-ish way as `[array[i,j,k], (i, j, k)]` and pass it to a function to be "multiprocessed".
Assuming that `matrices` is a list of all the matrices extracted from the original array and `myfunc` is the function doing the calculations, the code would look somewhat like this:

```py
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
from itertools import izip

def myfunc(finput):
    # Do some calculations...
    ...

    # ... and return the result and the index:
    return (result, finput[1])

# Make indices:
inds = np.rollaxis(np.indices((256, 256, 256)), 0, 4).reshape(-1, 3)

# Make function input from the matrices and the indices:
finput = izip(matrices, inds)

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
async_results = np.asarray(pool.map_async(myfunc, finput).get(999999))
```

However, it seems like `map_async` is actually creating this huge `finput`-list first: My CPU's aren't doing much, but the memory and swap get completely consumed in a matter of seconds, which is obviously not what I want.

Is there a way to pass this huge list to a multiprocessing function without the need to explicitly create it first?
Or do you know another way of solving this problem?

Thanks a bunch! :-)

Comment: Since you are using `get()` on `map_async()`, you probably don't want an *asynchronous* operation and should use `Pool.map()` instead.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the problem correctly, but have you considered imap or imap_unordered?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All `multiprocessing.Pool.map*` methods consume iterators fully<sup>[(demo code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047918/why-in-python-map-and-multiprocessing-pool-map-got-different-answers/7048202#7048202)</sup> as soon as the function is called. To feed the map function chunks of the iterator one chunk at a time, use `grouper_nofill`:

```
def grouper_nofill(n, iterable):
    '''list(grouper_nofill(3, 'ABCDEFG')) --> [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F'], ['G']]
    '''
    it=iter(iterable)
    def take():
        while 1: yield list(itertools.islice(it,n))
    return iter(take().next,[])

chunksize=256
async_results=[]
for finput in grouper_nofill(chunksize,itertools.izip(matrices, inds)):
    async_results.extend(pool.map_async(myfunc, finput).get())
async_results=np.array(async_results)
```

PS. `pool.map_async`'s `chunksize` parameter does something different: It breaks the iterable into chunks, then gives each chunk to a worker process which calls `map(func,chunk)`. This can give the worker process more data to chew on if `func(item)` finishes too quickly, but it does not help in your situation since the iterator still gets consumed fully immediately after the `map_async` call is issued.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution does indeed seem to work! For reference, I had to use pool.map_async(myfunc, finput).get(999999), but it works! However, it still uses a lot of memory (of course depending on the exact chunksize), and python doesn't seem to be garbage collecting during the run. Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: @digitaldingo: Hm, nothing comes to mind. It would be ideal if you can whittle down your code to a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and post it here.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem as well. instead of this:

```
res = p.map(func, combinations(arr, select_n))
```

do

```
res = p.imap(func, combinations(arr, select_n))
```

imap doesn't consume it!

Answer (score 0):

`Pool.map_async()` needs to know the length of the iterable to dispatch the work to multiple workers.  Since `izip` has no `__len__`, it converts the iterable into a list first, causing the huge memory usage you are experiencing.

You could try to sidestep this by creating your own `izip`-style iterator with `__len__`.

Comment: why does it need to know that?  why can't it simply feed all the idle workers and the wait?

Comment: @andrew - The first lines in `map_async()` (`multiprocessing/pool.py`) are actually `if not hasattr(iterable, '__len__'): iterable = list(iterable)`.  It needs to know the length to create a sufficiently large output list as the completion order of the workers is unknown.

Comment: hmmm.  it could construct that dynamically, couldn't it?  i'm just thinking this might be raised as an issue.  it seems like a valid request.

Comment: Yes it could do without `__len__` but it would be pretty complicated.  If result #321 is ready before #23, where should it be stored?  If the length is known, this gets way easier.

Comment: This is indeed interesting... `Pool.map_async()` might not know the length, but I do (256^3)---would it be possible to explicitly tell it the length? If not, maybe it should...