# multiprocessing.Pool.map_async() using much more memory than map()

Tags: python, memory, multiprocessing, out-of-memory

I have a list of objects, `clusters`, which I compare against each other using `itertools.combinations` and `map()`:

```
likelihoods = map(do_comparison, itertools.combinations(clusters, 2))
```

To speed this up I use multiple processes instead:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(6)
likelihoods = pool.map_async(do_comparison, itertools.combinations(clusters, 2)).get()
```

For small lists this works great. However, with 16700 objects in `clusters` (139436650 combinations) the `pool.map_async()` uses huge amounts of memory and my pc quickly runs out of memory, while `map()` has no memory problems with it.

My pc runs out of memory before the multiple processes are started, so my guess is that it's still dividing the chunks of data over the different processes. So I tried using `chunksize=1`, so that it only needs a small part of it, but this did now work.

Are there other methods to let `map_async()` use less memory?

Comment: Is `pool.imap` better?

Comment: @JanneKarila  `likelihoods = [x for x in pool.imap(do_comparison, itertools.combinations(clusters, 2))]` is better memory wise, but slower.

Comment: Slower than what? I understood that the `map_async` approach ran out of memory and did not finish.

Comment: It does not finish when `clusters` gets a size of 16000+, but when I time it with smaller `clusters` list `map_async` is faster.

Comment: See [Combining itertools and multiprocessing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7306522/222914)